# Generating linearly independent vectors in GF(p)

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's assume I already have a set of $k$ linearly independent vectors, each in $GF(p)^n$ (typically integers modulo $p$, with $p$ prime, in dimension $n$).
How can I generate a new vector in $GF(p)^n$  that is linearly independent to these ones ?

Over $\mathbb{R}^n$ I'd simply use Gram-Schmidt, but for integers modulo $p$, I do not see how that extends.

Comment: Gram--Schmidt wouldn't just be for finding independent vectors, but for finding orthonormal ones, which is stronger (and which only makes sense if you have an inner product to work with). Basic tools like Gaussian elimination are still available even when you're over a field of characteristic $p$.

Comment: By Gaussian elimination you can check in a routine way whether $(1,0,\dots,0)$ depends on your set of vectors. If it does, try $(0,1,0,\dots,0)$. Etc.

Comment: thanks ; though I do not immediately see how to use Gaussian elimination to generate an independent vector (expect for naively checking if the full set of k+1 vectors are indeed independent, and if not, generating randomly a new one until they are independent). I may be missing something obvious though.

Comment: mmm... given the comment by @ancientmathematician I assume this is the solution you had in mind as well ? isn't there a more direct way to do it (i.e., a more efficient way) ?

Comment: Gaussian Elimination is pretty efficient isn't it? BTW this is the Steinitz Exchange process.

Comment: in our context, $O(n^4)$ for $n$ Gaussian eliminations is very slow. In fact, we need to repeat this process $n^2/2$ times to build a matrix, and we build literally billions of matrices. If this is the best way though, I can accept this answer (we're trying to simplify our process in the meantime). I do not know about Steinitz Exchange... Thanks!